# make sptimerjob run on correct list

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I followed the code example at [How to: Create a Web Application-Scoped Timer Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx). It creates a timer job that runs on a list in the root of the web application. However, I need to make the timer job run on a list that is located in a subsite.

I think that a way to do this is to use the [Persisted] attribute as explained in [Creating Timer Jobs in SharePoint 2010 That Target Specific Web Applications (Wrox)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528518.aspx), but I have really struggled with how to get that to work.

Are there some code examples online that I haven't been able to find, that make this more clear? Or can someone write a code example that shows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer job that runs in the context of a web app (which is one of the two options (and the simplest)) has full access to the entire web app.

You you have to do to access a sub-site's list is refer to the site it is in, then find the subsite and finally the list.

Getting a site from a web app:

```
SPSite site = webApp.Sites[SiteName]
```

Setting a sub site from a site
Site or subsite used to create the site object:

```
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
```

Anything Else:

```
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl);
```

Get a site from a web (subsite):

```
SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
```

Safer:

```
SPList list = web.TryGetList(lsitName);
if(list != null)
{
//stuff...
}
```

If you need to use a list that exists in each site, then loop through the sites. If you need to access a list that exists in each subsite, loop through each site and subsite.

A timer job is simply a block of code that is registered, it can access anything the web app can access.

(Don't forget to .Dispose() your sites and webs or use using statements)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to directly consume SharePoint Service.

```
    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
           var dataContext = new TestDataContext(new Uri("http://url/sites/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"));
            dataContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            foreach (TaskListItem taskItem in dataContext.TaskList)
            {
                taskItem.Something = "else";
                dataContext.UpdateObject(taskItem);
            }
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```